# Using robot_localization, how can I calculate the GPS coordinates of any point on my robot?

Tags: navigation, navsat-transform-node, navsat-transform, jackal, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### The Problem (TL;DR)

I want to calculate the GPS coordinates of a random hardpoint on my robot, both directly from the GPS and via sensor fusion (EKFs).

---

### The Problem (in full)

This is a conceptual question about the "best practice" for calculating the GPS coordinates of any random hardpoint on my robot using the robot_localization package. I already have something that works, I just want to see if there is a better/more accurate way.

I'm using a Clearpath Robotics "Jackal" with a GPS mounted on top. So far I've been using the excellent robot_localization package to localize the robot using two EKFs. This diagram below shows a simplified version of my frame tree.  The first "local" EKF generates the `/odom` -> `/base_link` link. The second "global" EKF generates the `/map` -> `/odom` link. An instance of navsat_transform generates the `/map` -> `/utm` link (note that the /utm frame is located at the 0,0 point of the real UTM grid). The remaining links are set up in the robot URDF. The blue frames are fixed and do not move. The orange frames are fixed *relative to the other orange frames* but move with the robot and move relative to /map, /odom etc. I want to calculate the GPS coordinates of `/hardpoint` anywhere on my robot, could be the nose or a mounting point for a manipulator, the exact location isn't critical. The coordinates themselves could be in WGS84 or UTM although UTM is preferred because it's easier for frame transforms.

[image: image description]

I would like to calculate the coordinates in both of the following ways:

1. Directly from the GPS, i.e.`/auxgps` (so if the EKFs go nuts I still know where `/hardpoint` is)
2. Via the EKFs (so if I lose GPS lock briefly I still have coordinates for `/hardpoint`)

I currently have several possible ways of doing this:

- **[GPS Direct Option 1]** Use the `/auxgps` -> `/hardpoint`. This is more complicated than  it sounds because the result has to be *relative to the UTM grid*. I.e. the `/auxgps` -> `/hardpoint` transform by itself is meaningless because it just gives the location of `/hardpoint` *relative to* `/auxgps`, which I already know because I set it in the URDF. I'm a little unsure how to practically achieve this in code (python TF2 documentation isn't great)
- **[GPS Direct Option 2]** Calculate the difference between the translational components of the `/utm` -> `/auxgps` and `/utm` -> `/hardpoint` frame transforms. This will give you a difference in Nth/Est/Elv *relative to the UTM grid* Subtracting this from the UTM coordinates of `/auxgps` gives you the UTM coordinates of `/hardpoint`. Because this uses the *difference* between frame transforms, any error in the absolute position of `/utm` should come out in the wash. This method is dirty and more than a little hacky but it's easier to implement than option 1 above.
- **[Via EKF Option 1]** Modify the source code of navsat_transform. Navsat_transform publishes a topic called `/gps/fix`, which is normally the position of `/base_link` *relative to* `/map` converted to UTM coordinates, then to WGS84 coordinates. I could modify this to use `/hardpoint` instead of `/base_link`. I barely understand the navsat_transform source code so I'm not sure if this is possible and I'd rather not mess with another persons source code.
- **[Via EKF Option 2]** Simply take the translational component of the `/utm` -> `/hardpoint` frame transform. Because the `/utm` frame is located on the 0,0 point of the real-world UTM grid, this gives you UTM coordinates directly. This is by far the easiest method but I'm a little dubious about the legitimacy of it as a method of getting the coordinates.

So, out of the options above, which are the best practice for calculating the coordinates of `/hardpoint`, both directly from GPS and via the EKFs? Or if anyone has other suggestions I've love to hear them. And as always, enormous thanks to anyone who reads these horrific essays of mine, let alone take the time to answer them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249999/using-robot_localization,-how-can-i-calculate-the-gps-coordinates-of-any-point-on-my-robot?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your best bet is to write a small node that does a simple `tf` lookup from *hardpoint*->*utm* (which will work, as long as `n_t_n` is outputting the *map*->*utm* transform), and then use the `UTMtoLL()` method in `navsat_conversions.h` to get your lat/long.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-12-19**:
That's pretty much exactly what I've done and it seems to work pretty well. But I notice that it is *very* dependent on the accuracy of the EKF that creates /map. If the EKF is wrong, the coordinates are off, hence the need for GPS-direct coordinates. What are your thoughts on that?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-01-04**:
I think it's a bit outside the scope of the package, to be honest. What do you mean by "if the EKF is wrong"?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-01-05**:
I agree completely, my application is very uncommon but I wanted to ask anyway in case I'd missed something. I haven't done anything to optimize or tune the EKFs, and in open areas they're perfect. But some of my test areas involve sharp slopes near trees, and the EKFs... (1/2)

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-01-05**:
...Struggle in those are areas (haven’t had time to look into exactly why). The UTM horizontal and vertical position (location of `base_link` relative to `utm`) drifts, but the pure GPS position remains more accurate. So not wrong, just less accurate (sorry, my fault for not explaining properly).

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-01-13**:
If the robot is moving, I would expect the location of `base_link` relative to `utm` to change, but I'm guessing you're saying that it drifts even when the robot is still?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-01-15**:
Nope, if the robot is stationary the `base_link` -> `utm` transform is pretty constant. I'm calculating the location of `base_link` and `hardpoint` in a variety of different ways, with accuracy. Comments are too small for this so I will send you an email shortly with a better explanation.

**Comment by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on 2018-08-28**:
im still confused about [GPS Direct Option 1]. If i have RTK position of gps antenna w.r.t base station, and the gps antenna is on the side of the robot, how do i get the position of the center of the robot w.r.t to the base station?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-08-30**:
Can you please post a new question, @JadTawil?